# LSTM machine learning panda

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am actually trying to use TensorFlow and use the LSTM.
For that, I have data in the text file (10MB).

When I try to copy the data in numpy I get memory full Error.

Any suggestions how to get the data ready so that I can use in LSTM?

Reading the data from File before processing tensor flow with this function:

```py
def read_data(fname):
    with open(fname,encoding="utf8") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    content = [word for i in range(len(content)) for word in content[i].split()]
    content = np.array(content)
    return content
```

At the `np.array(content)`, it is giving memory full Error. How can I get around this so that I can use this data in LSTM in TensorFlow?

Please also suggest if there is any LSTM which can read large amounts of data

Comment: Please show us at least a few lines of your file.

Comment: You should rephrase your question. This has nothing to do with LSTMs or TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

Memory error indeed means that you cannot fit the numpy array into your memory because of the overhead of indexing string lists in numpy. The problem you are not creating a single matrix of words. Each word list of `content` has a different length, so calling `np.array` will create an array for each line and then add them into one large numpy array. This what numpy is for. Numpy is efficient why dealing with numerical tensors, not lists of list of strings.

Here is a [related question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31330/memoryerror-for-np-array).

If you plan to use TensforFlow, you can use [`tf.Dataset` API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset). It can load file line by line and you can then apply all the stuff you  need within TensorFlow, e.g., applying (calling the  [`map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) method) [`tf.string_split`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_split?hl=en) and [padding + batching](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) the data.

You will end up with something like this:

```py
tf.TextLineDataset(fname).map(lambda s: tf.strings.split([s])[0])
```

Note that before batching and passing it into LSTM you need to convert the strings to vocabulary indices and call embedding lookup on the indices.

Comment: Thank you for the response . Can you please help me with a example how we a read using DatasetAPI...I am not getting how to use that Please